# Convert from input type date to miliseconds using javascrip?

Tags: javascript, html

i'm trying to convert date (from a input type="date") to miliseconds but my output is "NaN, NaN" for some reason.

**HTML code:**

```
<html>
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
        <title>Stats</title>
    <h1>Stats</h1>
    </head>
    <body>
        <div class="contenedorFechas" for="fechas">
            <p>Insert date to promediate temps and humidity</p>
            <input type="date" id="fechaUno">
            <input type="date"  id="fechaDos">
            <input type ="button" id="btnPetDatos" value="Solcitar"> 
            <p id="pRespuesta">...</p>
        </div>
    </body>
            <script src="metodosJS.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
</html>
```

**Javascript:**

```
document.getElementById("btnPetDatos").onclick = function (){
    var auxUno = new Date(document.getElementById("fechaUno").value);
    var auxDos = new Date(document.getElementById("fechaDos").value);

    var fechaUno =  auxUno.getMilliseconds();
    var fechaDos =  auxDos.getMilliseconds();

    var Parametros = [fechaUno,fechaDos];

    document.getElementById("pRespuesta").innerHTML = Parametros;
}
```

Comment: What does `console.log(auxUno, auxDos)` show?

Comment: Also keep in mind that `getMilliseconds()` is going to return *just* the milliseconds, not the whole date in milliseconds.  If you want the whole date in milliseconds you want `getTime()` instead.

Comment: Actually, lol, I just realized your passing the whole DOM Element to the new Date() calls.  That's wrong man.  You have to give it the element values.  `new Date(document.getElementById("fechaUno").value);` or something of that nature

Comment: Instead of how to fix this issue, you actually need to think about how to debug when the result of javascript program is not expected. As @Taplar pointed out, you have put the DOM element as the parameter to the Date constructor. If the result is 'NaN  NaN', you can either print out the value of 'document.getElementById("fechaUno")' with 'console.log(....)' OR put a breakpoint in the js code and have a look at the values of variables in runtime.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You forgot to take value of date elements

```
document.getElementById("btnPetDatos").onclick = function (){
    var auxUno = new Date(document.getElementById("fechaUno").value);
    var auxDos = new Date(document.getElementById("fechaDos").value);

    var fechaUno =  auxUno.getMilliseconds();
    var fechaDos =  auxDos.getMilliseconds();
    var Parametros = [fechaUno,fechaDos];

    document.getElementById("pRespuesta").innerHTML = Parametros;
}
```

And are u sure to use `getMilliseconds()` method because u choose time  so there is not hour or minute so u will take 0 always. 
 u can use `getTime()` method it return an integer to you. So you can use them how you want.

Comment: The format returned from a date input is YYYY-MM-DD which is parsed as UTC, so users may see a different result than they expect.